# Detecting all circles in a graph

Tags: java, graph, geometry, graph-algorithm

I have a directed graph stored in a Map data structure, where the key is the node's ID 
and the [value] is the array of the nodeIds of the nodes which are pointed by the key node.

```
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
map.put("1", new String[] {"2", "5"});
map.put("2", new String[] {"3"});
map.put("3", new String[] {"4"});
map.put("4", new String[] {"4"});
map.put("5", new String[] {"5", "9"});
map.put("6", new String[] {"5"});
map.put("7", new String[] {"6"});
map.put("8", new String[] {"6"});
map.put("9", new String[] {"10"});
map.put("10", new String[] {"5"});
map.put("11", new String[] {"11"});
```

I wrote a recursive searching algorithm which tries to locate the circle in the graph.

```
Set<String> nodes = map.keySet();

    for(String node : nodes) {
        List<String> forbiddens = new ArrayList<>(); // This list stores the touched nodes, during the process.
        forbiddens.add(node);
        recursiveSearch(node, forbiddens);
    }
```

The function is called by the code above.

```
private void recursiveSearch(String nodeId, List<String> forbiddens) {
    String[] neighbours = map.get(nodeId); // The given node's neighbours
    for(String neighbour : neighbours) {
        for(String forbidden : forbiddens) {
            if(neighbour.equals(forbidden)) {
                ways.add( getClone(forbidden) ); //getClone returns the copy of a given List, "ways" is a List<List<String>> which contains the lists of paths which are leading to a circle in the graph
                return;
            }
        }
        forbiddens.add(neighbour);
        recursiveSearch(neighbour, forbiddens);
        forbiddens.remove(neighbour);
    }
}
```

Some paths contains extra nodes (which aren't in the circle) that I would like to get rid of.
I would like to ask for help to select the nodes from the "ways" lists to get the actual nodes of the circle.

Can this algorithm find ALL the circles in the graph?

Comment: can you explain a bit more about what you mean by 'circle'? is circle a reference to itself? maybe you can add a pic to explain what you mean, e.g. a picture from the graph itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a circle in a directed graph represents a strongly connected component, you can use any of the algorithms referenced on the wikipedia page for finding strongly connected components https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component - for instance Tarjan's algorithm which is based on depth-first search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm

Edit: It is possible that a strongly connected component contains multiple circles that share nodes with each other. So, a manual checking of each component must follow, but should be easy.

Comment: While all strongly connected components are circles not all circles are strongly connected components.

Comment: consider this image https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#/media/File:Scc.png a->b->f->e->a is a circle but not a strongly connected component

Comment: a->b->f->e->a is not a circle - there is no edge from f to e.

Answer (score 0):

[image: test graph]  [image]

```
package neo4j

import java.net.URI
import org.apache.spark.graphx.{Edge, EdgeRDD, Graph, Pregel, VertexId, VertexRDD}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.opencypher.spark.api.CAPSSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row}
import org.opencypher.okapi.api.graph.GraphName
import org.opencypher.okapi.api.io.conversion.{NodeMapping, RelationshipMapping}
import org.opencypher.spark.api.io.neo4j.{Neo4jConfig, Neo4jPropertyGraphDataSource}
import org.opencypher.spark.api.io.{CAPSNodeTable, CAPSRelationshipTable}
import org.opencypher.spark.impl.io.neo4j.external.Neo4j
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.util.Random
import scala.util.control.Breaks

object TestV  extends App {
  //1) Create CAPS session and retrieve Spark session
  implicit val session: CAPSSession = CAPSSession.local()
  val spark = session.sparkSession
  //11)  Connect to Neo4j
  val boltWriteURI: URI = new URI("bolt://localhost:7687")
  val neo4jWriteConfig: Neo4jConfig = new Neo4jConfig(boltWriteURI, "neo4j", Some("123abc"), true)
  val neo4jResult: Neo4jPropertyGraphDataSource = new Neo4jPropertyGraphDataSource(neo4jWriteConfig)(session)
  val neo4jConnection = Neo4j(neo4jWriteConfig, session.sparkSession)

  val neo4jResultName: GraphName = new GraphName("neo4jgraph")
  neo4jResult.delete(neo4jResultName)
  //node : no, name;  relation : source, target, amount
  val len = 9
  var node_seq = collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Long, String)]()
  var relation_seq = collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Long, Long, Double)]()
  for (i <- 0 until len) {
    node_seq.+=((i.toLong, s"name$i"))
    i match {
      case a if a == len - 1 => relation_seq.+=((0.toLong, a.toLong, Random.nextDouble() * len))
      case _ => relation_seq = relation_seq.+=((i + 1.toLong, i.toLong, Random.nextDouble() * len))
    }
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
      Thread.sleep(100)
      //println(node_seq.length + " " + relation_seq.length)
    }
  }
  //println(node_seq)
  //println(relation_seq)
  node_seq.+=((9.toLong, "name9"))
  node_seq.+=((10.toLong, "name10"))
  node_seq.+=((11.toLong, "name11"))
  node_seq.+=((12.toLong, "name12"))
  relation_seq.+=((0L, 0L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((3L, 3L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((0L, 3L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((0L, 9L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((7L, 10L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((10L, 7L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((7L, 10L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((10L, 7L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((10L, 11L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((11L, 12L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((12L, 10L, Random.nextDouble() * len))

  relation_seq.+=((0L, 0L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((3L, 3L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((3L, 0L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((9L, 0L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((10L, 7L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((7L, 10L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((10L, 7L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((7L, 10L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((11L, 10L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((12L, 11L, Random.nextDouble() * len))
  relation_seq.+=((10L, 12L, Random.nextDouble() * len))

  //3) cache the dataframe
  //println("#####" +node_seq.length + " " + relation_seq.length)
  val nodesDF: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(node_seq).toDF("no", "name").
    withColumn("id1", monotonically_increasing_id()).select("id1", "name", "no").cache()
  nodesDF.count()
  //nodesDF.show
  val relsDF: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(relation_seq).toDF("source", "target", "amount").
    withColumn("id2", monotonically_increasing_id()).select("id2", "source", "target", "amount").cache()
  relsDF.count()
  //relsDF.show

  import spark.implicits._

  //8) mapping the columns
  val node_mapping = NodeMapping.withSourceIdKey("id1").withImpliedLabel("Person").withPropertyKeys("no", "name")
  val rel_mapping = RelationshipMapping.withSourceIdKey("id2").withSourceStartNodeKey("source")
    .withSourceEndNodeKey("target").withRelType("KNOWS").withPropertyKeys("amount")

  //9)  create tables
  val node_table = CAPSNodeTable(node_mapping, nodesDF)
  val rel_table = CAPSRelationshipTable(rel_mapping, relsDF)

  //10) Create graph
  val graph = session.readFrom(node_table, rel_table)

  //12) Store graph in neo4j
  neo4jResult.store(neo4jResultName, graph)
  val node_result = neo4jConnection.cypher("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n.no as no, n.name as name").loadNodeRdds
  val node_fields: Array[StructField] = Array(new StructField("no", LongType, true), StructField("name", StringType, true))
  val nodeSchema = new StructType().add(node_fields(0)).add(node_fields(1))
  //session.sparkSession.createDataFrame(node_result, nodeSchema).show(10)
  val rel_result = neo4jConnection.rels("MATCH (m:Person)-[r:KNOWS]->(n:Person) RETURN m.no as source, n.no as target, r.amount as amount").loadRelRdd
  val rel_fields: Array[StructField] = Array(new StructField("source", LongType, true), StructField("target", LongType, true),
    StructField("amount", DoubleType, true))
  val relSchema = new StructType().add(rel_fields(0)).add(rel_fields(1)).add(rel_fields(2))
  //session.sparkSession.createDataFrame(rel_result, relSchema).show(10)
  val edges: EdgeRDD[Double] = EdgeRDD.fromEdges(rel_result.map { case Row(a: Long, b: Long, c: Double) => Edge(a, b, c) })
  val vertices: VertexRDD[(Long, String)] = VertexRDD(node_result.map { case Row(a: Long, b: String) => (a, (a, b)) })
  val graph_spark = Graph[(Long, String), Double](vertices, edges)
  val final_graph_fit_tmp1 = graph_spark.removeSelfEdges().mapVertices((id, attr) =>
    (new collection.mutable.HashMap[Long, collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]]().+=
    ((id, new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]().+=
    (collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long](id))))
      , new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]](), 0))

  val find_circle = Pregel(final_graph_fit_tmp1, new collection.mutable.HashMap
    [Long, collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]]())(
    (id, attr, msg) => {
      Thread.sleep(10)
      if (id == 4) {
        println("================================")
        println("                " + attr._3 + "                ")
        println("================================")
      }
      println("id: " + id + " msg: " + msg + " attr: " + attr)
      val ss: collection.mutable.HashMap[Long, collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]] =
        new collection.mutable.HashMap[Long, collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]]()
      for (ss_a <- attr._1) {
        val cpy = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]()
        for (e <- ss_a._2) {
          cpy.+=(e)
        }
        ss.+=(ss_a._1 -> cpy)
        if (msg.contains(ss_a._1)) {
          for (s_m <- msg(ss_a._1)) {
            for (s_a <- ss_a._2) {
              if (attr._3 == 3 && id == 11)
                println("order operate: " + s_a + " " + s_m)
              if (s_a.-(s_a.head) == s_m.-(s_m.last))
                ss(ss_a._1).+=(s_a.++(s_m))
              if (attr._3 > 1) {
                val set = new collection.mutable.HashSet[Int]()
                for (i <- ss(ss_a._1).indices) {
                  if (ss(ss_a._1)(i) == (s_a)) {
                    set.add(i)
                  }
                }
                val set2 = ss(ss_a._1).indices.toSet.diff(set)
                val listBuf = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]()
                for (i <- set2) {
                  listBuf.append(ss(ss_a._1)(i))
                }
                ss(ss_a._1).clear()
                ss(ss_a._1).append(listBuf:_*)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      for (key <- msg.keys.toSet.diff(ss.keys.toSet)) {
        val cpy = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]()
        for (e <- msg(key)) {
          cpy.+=(e)
        }
        ss.+=((key, cpy))
      }
      val set_remove: collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Long, collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long])] =
        new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Long, collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long])]()
      for (s <- ss) {
        for (e <- s._2) {
          if (attr._3 > 0) {
            if (e.isEmpty) {
              set_remove.+=((s._1, e))
            } else if (attr._3 == 1) {
              ss.remove(id)
            } else if (e.contains(id) || e.size != attr._3) {
              set_remove.+=((s._1, e))
              if (e.size == attr._3) {
                attr._2.+=(e)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      for (s <- set_remove) {
        val set = new collection.mutable.HashSet[Int]()
        for (i <- ss(s._1).indices) {
          if (ss(s._1)(i) == s._2) {
            set.add(i)
          }
        }
        val set2 = ss(s._1).indices.toSet.diff(set)
        val listBuf = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]()
        for (i <- set2) {
          listBuf.append(ss(s._1)(i))
        }
        ss(s._1).clear()
        ss(s._1).append(listBuf:_*)
      }
      (ss.filter(s => s._2.nonEmpty), attr._2.filter(s => s.nonEmpty), attr._3 + 1)
    },
    trp => if (trp.srcAttr._1.keys.nonEmpty) {
      val ss = new collection.mutable.HashMap[Long, collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]]()
      for (s <- trp.srcAttr._1) {
        if (ss.contains(trp.srcId)) {
          ss(trp.srcId).++=(s._2)
        } else {
          val cpy = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]()
          for (e <- s._2 if e.size - trp.srcAttr._3 < 2 && e.size - trp.srcAttr._3 > -2 && e.size - trp.dstAttr._3 < 2 && e.size - trp.dstAttr._3 > -2) {
            cpy.+=(e)
          }
          if (cpy.nonEmpty)
            ss.+=(trp.srcId -> cpy)
        }
      }
      if (ss.nonEmpty)
        Iterator({
          (trp.dstId, ss)
        })
      else
        Iterator.empty
    } else Iterator.empty,
    (a, b) => {
      val ss = new collection.mutable.HashMap[Long, collection.mutable.ListBuffer[collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet[Long]]]()
      ss.++=(a)
      ss.++=(b)
      ss
    }).cache()
  println("================================")
  println("                vertices                ")
  println("================================")
  p**rintln(find_circle.vertices.mapValues(v => v._2.toSet).take(15).mkString("##;\r\n"))
  System.exit(0)
}
```

output:

```
================================
                0                
================================
id: 4 msg: Map() attr: (Map(4 -> ListBuffer(Set(4))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 11 msg: Map() attr: (Map(11 -> ListBuffer(Set(11))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 0 msg: Map() attr: (Map(0 -> ListBuffer(Set(0))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 1 msg: Map() attr: (Map(1 -> ListBuffer(Set(1))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 6 msg: Map() attr: (Map(6 -> ListBuffer(Set(6))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 3 msg: Map() attr: (Map(3 -> ListBuffer(Set(3))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 12 msg: Map() attr: (Map(12 -> ListBuffer(Set(12))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 9 msg: Map() attr: (Map(9 -> ListBuffer(Set(9))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 7 msg: Map() attr: (Map(7 -> ListBuffer(Set(7))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 8 msg: Map() attr: (Map(8 -> ListBuffer(Set(8))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 10 msg: Map() attr: (Map(10 -> ListBuffer(Set(10))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 5 msg: Map() attr: (Map(5 -> ListBuffer(Set(5))),ListBuffer(),0)
id: 2 msg: Map() attr: (Map(2 -> ListBuffer(Set(2))),ListBuffer(),0)
================================
                1                
================================
id: 4 msg: Map(5 -> ListBuffer(Set(5))) attr: (Map(4 -> ListBuffer(Set(4))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 11 msg: Map(10 -> ListBuffer(Set(10)), 12 -> ListBuffer(Set(12))) attr: (Map(11 -> ListBuffer(Set(11))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 0 msg: Map(1 -> ListBuffer(Set(1)), 3 -> ListBuffer(Set(3)), 9 -> ListBuffer(Set(9))) attr: (Map(0 -> ListBuffer(Set(0))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 1 msg: Map(2 -> ListBuffer(Set(2))) attr: (Map(1 -> ListBuffer(Set(1))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 6 msg: Map(7 -> ListBuffer(Set(7))) attr: (Map(6 -> ListBuffer(Set(6))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 3 msg: Map(4 -> ListBuffer(Set(4)), 0 -> ListBuffer(Set(0))) attr: (Map(3 -> ListBuffer(Set(3))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 12 msg: Map(11 -> ListBuffer(Set(11)), 10 -> ListBuffer(Set(10))) attr: (Map(12 -> ListBuffer(Set(12))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 9 msg: Map(0 -> ListBuffer(Set(0))) attr: (Map(9 -> ListBuffer(Set(9))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 7 msg: Map(8 -> ListBuffer(Set(8)), 10 -> ListBuffer(Set(10))) attr: (Map(7 -> ListBuffer(Set(7))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 8 msg: Map(0 -> ListBuffer(Set(0))) attr: (Map(8 -> ListBuffer(Set(8))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 10 msg: Map(11 -> ListBuffer(Set(11)), 7 -> ListBuffer(Set(7)), 12 -> ListBuffer(Set(12))) attr: (Map(10 -> ListBuffer(Set(10))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 5 msg: Map(6 -> ListBuffer(Set(6))) attr: (Map(5 -> ListBuffer(Set(5))),ListBuffer(),1)
id: 2 msg: Map(3 -> ListBuffer(Set(3))) attr: (Map(2 -> ListBuffer(Set(2))),ListBuffer(),1)
....
....
================================
                    9                
================================
....
....
================================
                vertices                
================================
(4,Set(Set(5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 3, 4), Set(5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)))##;
(11,Set(Set(10, 11), Set(12, 11), Set(10, 12, 11)))##;
(0,Set(Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0), Set(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0), Set(9, 0), Set(1, 2, 3, 0), Set(3, 0)))##;
(1,Set(Set(2, 3, 0, 1), Set(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1)))##;
(6,Set(Set(7, 8, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6), Set(7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)))##;
(3,Set(Set(0, 3), Set(0, 1, 2, 3), Set(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 3), Set(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3)))##;
(12,Set(Set(11, 12), Set(10, 12), Set(11, 10, 12)))##;
(9,Set(Set(0, 9)))##;
(7,Set(Set(10, 7), Set(8, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Set(8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)))##;
(8,Set(Set(0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), Set(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)))##;
(10,Set(Set(11, 10), Set(7, 10), Set(12, 10), Set(11, 12, 10)))##;
(5,Set(Set(6, 7, 8, 0, 3, 4, 5), Set(6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))##;
(2,Set(Set(3, 0, 1, 2), Set(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2)))

Process finished with exit code 0
```