# How to find cycles pass through particular edge?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I know that Euler Cycle is a Cycle which pass through every edge exactly once.

However I want to know if there is any known algorithm to find cycles in a graph which pass through a particular edge?

For eg in particular graph Let's say I just want to find cycles which go through Edge A-B then there are cycles ABD and AEB

Is there any way to find ALL these particular edge cycles without listing all cycles in graph?

[image]

Comment: So, to make the question more clear, please tell if you want to get **ALL** circles or **ANY** circles?

Comment: I actually want all circles, as I want to find total number.

Comment: Be aware that if a graph is a complete graph, there may be **EXTREMELY** large quantity of the result.

Comment: If you want only the number, please update the question, it would be a different case.

Comment: Yes, does not matter. I have the computational power.
I want both. 

Number is top priority

Comment: If you want to list all circles, it would be a NPC problem.

Comment: Easy.  Remove edge AB, then find all remaining paths from A to B.  Adding the AB edge to each of these paths forms a cycle that includes AB.  I'm not going to go into how to find all paths from A to B, since I can't really believe that is what you want.

Comment: @MattTimmermans This is a good solution. Any way I can incorporate length in this? I dont want to list all paths from A to B but rather paths with length 2/3/4.

Answer (score -1):

#### Analysis:

1. If you want to list all cycles of a graph, it is obviously an NPC problem, because the output set is not polynomial (Think about a complete graph). In this case, you can just apply *Depth first search* on the graph.
2. If you want to get the count, this problem can reduce to another question: [Detecting all circles in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31189582/2544762)

#### Problem reduction:

Now  we know how to tell the number of all cycles of a graph `G`:

```
int count_cycles(Graph G) {
    ...
}
```

And we want to know how many cycles that passes a specific edge `E`:

So we can define a new graph `G'`, it breaks the edge `E` of `G` and take the result.

So the finally result is:

```
int count_cycles_passing_edge(Graph G, Edge E) {
    Graph G_ = G.exclude(E);
    return count_cycles(G) - count_cycles(G_);
}
```

Because

1. The cycles passing `E` equals all the cycles excluding all cycles not passing `E`
2. The cycles not passing `E` equals all cycles in `G'`

So, the problem now reduced to *How to get all cycles in a graph*.

So, you can look into [Detecting all circles in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31189582/2544762)
, and may got a efficient way to solve the reduced problem.

Comment: thanks it is good. Any idea on how I can incorporate length in this? I dont want to list all paths from A to B but rather paths with length 2/3/4.

Comment: Listing exponentially much stuff can't be NP-complete since you can't do exponentially much in polynomial time, whether deterministic or nondeterministic.